# My React-Native-Elements cards are not showing up correctly on my device

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-elements

I am working with React Native Elements cards.

While it is working properly in the browser (all devices) it isn't working in the expo app on my device.
The cards are rendered on top of each other and are not clickable.

I tried to look it up on google but I found nothing about this issue.
Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Resources:

[Screenshot of the cards in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVdct.png)

[Screenshot of the cards on my device with expo app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBdOB.jpg)

Here is a piece of my code from a card:

```
<View style={styles.item2}>
    <Card containerStyle={{
      width: widthPercentageToDP('40%'),
      height: widthPercentageToDP('40%'),
      justifyContent: 'center',
    }}>
      <Text>...</Text>
      <Icon
        name='search'
        type='material'
        color='black'
        size={widthPercentageToDP('28%')}
        onPress={() => {props.onChange("care")}} />
    </Card>
  </View>
```

Comment: Well I fixed it, I used for every card a new View with a new flex:1 and that didn't work well.